# Unable to apply quota to a group with ACL persmissiions on MAC OS X SL Server

Tags: mac, command-line

I am trying to apply quota to a group using edquota to a group I created through workgroup manager, but the group does not appear in repquota -a -g command. It appears that quota apply to only groups having POSIX permissions (I hope i am wrong).

How do I add a new group, give it ACL permissions on sharepoint and apply quota to it which also works.

Thanks